# binding this in a jQuery callback in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm having trouble with `this` in a backbone.js project.

This is my view:

```
app.SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function() {
    var that = this;
    $.getJSON(someURL, function(result) {
      that.property = result.something;
    });

    return this;
  }
})
```

Inexplicably, inside the `getJSON` callback `that.property` is set, but as soon as that function is finished - i.e. at `return this` - `that.property` equals `undefined`, same as `this.property`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the `$.getJSON` function is asynchronous, so `return this` occurs before `that.property = result.something`

Comment: @jackwanders you should add this as an answer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why you are not using Models. Answering to your question, there are different solutions, the first one:

Using events:

```
app.SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function() {
    var that = this;
    $.getJSON(someURL, function(result) {
      that.property = result.something;
      that.trigger('DataLoaded', that);
    });

    return this;
  }
});
var view = new app.SomeView();
view.on('DataLoaded', function(theView){ 
  console.log( theView );
});
```

Second one, you need to add a callback and pass it:

```
app.SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({

  render: function(callback) {
    var that = this;
    $.getJSON(someURL, function(result) {
      that.property = result.something;
      callback(that);
    });
    return this;
  }
});
var view = new app.SomeView();
view.render( function(theView){ 
  console.log( theView );
});
```

My answers was written for fix the question that you created. But for a long term improvement, do you know that Models has a fetch method that basically loads JSON from the server and associate it the Model? 
http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch
This is how I will load the JSON:

```
app.SomeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot : someURL
});
app.SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize : function(){
     this.model.on('change', this.render);
  },
  render: function() {
    console.log( this.model.toJSON() );
    return this;
  }
});
var view = new app.SomeView(new app.SomeModel());
view.model.fetch();
```

Comment: Yes, as a matter of fact I actually ended up implementing the first solution (events). I'm not using a model because the `$.getJSON` is actually querying an external API, i.e. not my backend. I might actually wrap that functionality in a model, in order to have `fetch`. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Backbone support it: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse you could parse your custom third party server response and convert IT into your model.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in my comment, `$.getJSON` is asynchronous. The `render` function continues to execute while `$.getJSON` fetches the appropriate URL, so `return this;` ends up executing before `that.property = result.something`

Comment: but if i debug the code with firebug, i can see `that.property getting` set, and then loosing its value at the end of the callback.

Comment: try this: add `console.log('got json: '+that.property)` after the line where you set `that.property`, and add `console.log('end of function: '+that.property)` right before `return this;`. The order of these two log statements should inform you as to whether the function is returning before `$.getJSON` completes.